# Dependency walker is very slow for wintrust.dll

Tags: dll, windows-10, dependency-walker

I use Dependency Walker to open `wintrust.dll` on my Windows 10 and it takes around 40 seconds! When it is opened, I see very strange picture of recurring calls between `KERNEL32.DLL` and `API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSTHREADS-L1-1-1.DLL`:

[image]

I suppose this is the source of the problem. When I try to open my own dll, that includes `wintrust.dll` on separate paths, it might take up to 10 minutes (!) to open.

Why is this happening?

- Dependency Walker for Win64, v2.2.6
- Windows 10 x64 Version 1709 (OS Build 16299.248)
- wintrust.dll File version 10.0.16299.248
- kernel32.dll File version 10.0.16299.15
- api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-1.dll File version 10.0.10586.9

Comment: Depends has not been maintained in a very long time.  The author no doubt gave up on it when the going got tough, the loader got too many features to be able to do this correctly.  Including this, it just doesn't know beans about these MinWin forwarders.  You can't assume this can come to a good end.  If you also don't tell us why this matters then it gets to be pretty hard to help you.

Comment: I just don't know any other convenient alternative to depends. Could you suggest any?

Comment: Alternative to what?  You still have not described the real problem you are trying to tackle.

Comment: I have a .dll and I would like to know which dlls it depends on. I want to see whether OS is able to find those dlls or not. If yes, where does it find them. I want to see which of them are delay-loaded.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Don't use dependency walker. Here's one good alternative I'm aware of: [Dependencies by Lucasg](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies). Unlike dependency walker - it is aware of [ApiSets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh802935%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and thus will not recurse indefinitely.